# Why this CASE...END CASE clause in a trigger of MySQL caused an error prompt?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, case

In a trigger of MySQL, I wrote such clause:

```
CASE v_index
    WHEN 1 THEN:
        UPDATE `device` SET `filter1_left` = `filter1_left` + 1 WHERE `id` = 100;
    WHEN 2 THEN:
        UPDATE `device` SET `filter2_left` = `filter2_left` + 1 WHERE `id` = 100;
    WHEN 3 THEN:
        UPDATE `device` SET `filter3_left` = `filter3_left` + 1 WHERE `id` = 100;
    WHEN 4 THEN:
        UPDATE `device` SET `filter4_left` = `filter4_left` + 1 WHERE `id` = 100;
    WHEN 5 THEN:
        UPDATE `device` SET `filter5_left` = `filter5_left` + 1 WHERE `id` = 100;
END CASE;
```

But I can't create this trigger successfully, receiving the following error prompt:

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': UPDATE `device` SET `filter1_left` = `filter1_left` + 1' at line 17

And by the way, I have three more questions:

1. I felt the above clause kind of verbose. Are there any methods to simplify it and achieve the same goal more elegantly?
2. Can I omit the colon following the 'THEN'?
3. Can I put the UPDATE... sentence in the same line of 'WHEN...THEN'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no colon `:` after `THEN`, so remove all those colons

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves my problem. But I'm so confused by the book <Beginning PHP and MySQL From Novice to Professional> (By W. Jason Gilmore, Apress 2010), which says there should be a colon following the 'THEN'. Wow, how could it be? @RacilHilan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no colon `:` after `THEN`, so remove all those colons.

> I felt the above clause kind of verbose. Are there any methods to simplify it and achieve the same goal more elegantly?

I started writing it, but Gordon Linoff beat me to it (as usual :-)), so see his answer.

> Can I omit the colon following the 'THEN'?

You can't, you have to :-)

> Can I put the UPDATE... sentence in the same line of 'WHEN...THEN'?

Yes. SQL doesn't care about whitespace in general, so a space or line break are all the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! You answered every of my questions so carefully, so humourously, and so clearly. It's so kind of you! But I'm so confused by the book <Beginning PHP and MySQL From Novice to Professional> (By W. Jason Gilmore, Apress 2010), which says there should be a colon following the 'THEN'. Wow, how could it be? @RacilHilan

Answer (score 1):

You *could* fix the data structure, so you have five rows instead of five columns.  But you can also do this in one `update`:

```
UPDATE device
    SET filter1_left = filter1_left + (CASE WHEN v_index = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        filter2_left = filter2_left + (CASE WHEN v_index = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        filter3_left = filter3_left + (CASE WHEN v_index = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        filter4_left = filter4_left + (CASE WHEN v_index = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        filter5_left = filter5_left + (CASE WHEN v_index = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    WHERE `id` = 100 AND v_index IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's so kind of you. Thank you! But I'm so confused by the book <Beginning PHP and MySQL From Novice to Professional> (By W. Jason Gilmore, Apress 2010), which says there should be a colon following the 'THEN'. Wow, how could it be? @GordonLinoff